# how to copy a NSDictionary with keyvalues

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a method that is returning some values in its parameters. These values are NSDictionaries that have KeyValues.

I would like to know how to make a copy of these NSDictionaries that include the keyvalues.

Currently this is what I am trying to do.

//.h

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDic;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *tempDic;
```

//.m

```
@synthesize tempDic;


- (void)reciverMethod:(NSDictionary *)myDictionary {

// I would like to get my method specific variable **myDictionary** and copy it into my global dictionary value tempDic like so

tempDic = [myDictionary mutableCopy]; //  this dosnt work

}
```

the thing behing myDictionary might have several keyvalues you can access using

```
myDictionary.firstvalue
myDictionary.secondvalue
myDictionary.thirdvalue
```

but when i try to use tempDic none of those keys are avalible..

i.e.
    tempDic.firstvalue 
    tempDic.secondvalue 
    tempDic.thirdvalue

dosnt work...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a global named `tempDic` and a property named `tempDic`? That's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) remove  this, `NSMutableDictionary *tempDic;`

having this is enough,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *tempDic;
```

Since the tempDic object is **strong, nonatomic**

```
- (void)reciverMethod:(NSDictionary)myDictionary {
self.tempDic = myDictionary;
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
id value1 = [self.tempDic objectForKey:@"firstvalue"];
id value2 = [self.tempDic objectForKey:@"secondvalue"];
id value3 = [self.tempDic objectForKey:@"thirdvalue"];
```

Comment: Why do you need a copy of that Dictionary ?

Comment: because I would like to use the values in it in another method so I am trying to pass it to a globally accessible variable.

Comment: I am getting this error when i try to access the keys
**Property 'firstvalue' not found on object of type 'NSMutableDictionary *'** and its definatly there when i log out myDictionary

Comment: ok, by doing this self.tempDic = myDictionary; you pass it to a globally accessible variable self.tempDic. Then what's your problem ?

Comment: the problem is I cannot access tempDic.firstValue etc none of those properties are avalible.

Comment: Yes sure, tempDic.firstValue is not the way to access those values. Try this :-> id value1 = [self.tempDic objectForKey:@"firstvalue"];

Comment: oh right i was treating it like an NSObject class variable... my bad